# Extra space being added to array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

My XML web service is sending an extra space in a datetime parameter of an array. Prior to April 1, the format was coming over as:

```
Sun Mar 31 02:05:49 2012 GMT
```

...but as of April 1, it was being reformatted as:

```
Sun Apr  1 02:05:49 2012 GMT (Note the extra space between "Apr" and "1")
```

The problem is I'm exploding my array with a blankspace (`" "`) to take the *[Month]+[Date]+[Year]* but now I'm getting *[Month]+[blank]+[Timestamp]*.

Is there an array function to count backwards so I get *[timezone] [year] [timestamp] [date]* etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly relevant question: [Unset blank array items on the fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317362/unset-blank-array-items-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split using regular expression

```
$array = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $date);
```

This will use one or more whitespaces as separator

Comment: Thanks Darhazer...let me try that

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`strtotime()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on the whole string?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Alex but I have to get this into a MSFT-friendly format

Comment: @Lübnah: Who cares, the impact is so small that it doesn't mean anything. However, it ensures that the date is parsed correctly, unlike the current OP's method.

Comment: @netcoder Do you know of any performance metrics that prove the impact to be small? Scalability has a way of magnifying seemingly tiny issues.

Comment: @Lübnah: Had the OP used this technique in the first place, he wouldn't be having this issue now. What's that worth? :)

Comment: @Lübnah: You have to ask yourself the exact opposite question: do you know of any performance metrics that prove the impact *not* to be small? If you don't, then you shouldn't bother optimizing prematurely.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: True. I'd still be interested to learn which approach is more performant. If only php.net listed the time complexity of their built-ins! :P Still, it really depends on what OP is trying to accomplish, I guess.

Comment: Consider also -- this technique will silently and gracefully handle just about any future change to the date format in the source XML file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse a date, use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$time = 'Sun Apr  1 02:05:49 2012 GMT';

$month = date('M', $ts); // Apr
$day = date('j', $ts);   // 1
$year = date('Y', $ts);  // 2012
```

It also ensures that the time is converted to your current timezone, which you can change like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```

Another alternative is to simply use [`strptime`](http://php.net/strptime), which actually has been created to *parse dates*, but do not take timezones in consideration:

```
$parsed = strptime($time, '%c');
```

Answer (score 1):

As Alex Howansky suggests, you should use some date/time parsing function. You can then use date() or DateTime::format() to output the date in your desired format:

```
$formatA = 'Sat Mar 31 02:05:49 2012 GMT';
$formatB = 'Sun Apr  1 02:05:49 2012 GMT';

var_dump(
    new DateTime( $formatA ),
    new DateTime( $formatB ),
    date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $formatA ) ),
    date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $formatB ) )
);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
        string(19) "2012-03-31 02:05:49"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(2)
    ["timezone"]=>
        string(3) "GMT"
}

object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
        string(19) "2012-04-01 02:05:49"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(2)
    ["timezone"]=>
        string(3) "GMT"
}

string(19) "2012-03-31 04:05:49"

string(19) "2012-04-01 04:05:49"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter()` to strip out all array entries that evaluate to FALSE. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Although, I should note, I would probably use Darhazer's solution, myself. Just mentioning array_filter() here, as I'm not sure what the performance overhead of using `preg_split()` is in comparison to `array_filter()`.